# Why is malloc in global namespace?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

From what I understand, one of the reasons the C++ versions of C libraries like `stdlib.h` (`cstdlib`) were introduced was so that the global namespace is not polluted.

But it turns out that I am able to use `malloc` in the global namespace even though I did not `#include <stdlib.h>`.

So then why should I `#include <cstdlib>` and then use `std::malloc`?

(I'm using g++ version 4.8.2)

Comment: Any header may include any other header

Comment: I'm using malloc in the placement new operator.

Comment: The `<*.h>` C headers are deprecated, yet lots of code still relies on those names being in the global namespace. Maybe that has something to do with why the standard explicitly permits the `<c*>` headers to put names in the global namespace, or maybe not.

Comment: You are "allowed" by your compiler, but not by the standard. The standard allows c* headers to put symbols in the global namespace because implementers find it so much easier to just include C headers.

Comment: [Use the source Luke](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00834_source.html).  Note the #include.  Just about everybody does this, it still has to link.

Comment: @PeteBecker OP seemed to be saying that `malloc` had been defined even though neither `stdlib.h` and `cstdlib` was included . (So there are two issues, the header inclusion and then the global namespace)

Comment: @M.M - could be. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @user22119: Can you explain your comment about the "placement new()" operator? As far as I can tell, you shouldn't really be using `malloc()` yourself at all. (As opposed to, say, `realloc()` maybe).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There used to be a requirement that the C headers (`*.h`) only put names into the global namespace and that the corresponding C++ headers only put names into `std`. That turned out to be impractical, and was often not followed. So the standards committee standardized existing practice, and changed the rule so that the C headers **must** put names into the global namespace and **may** put them into `std`, and that the C++ headers **must** put names into `std` and **may** put them into the global namespace.

The reason that the old rule was impractical is simply that it would require duplicating all of the C header content inside namespace `std`, with a corresponding burden in maintenance of having two sets of code to update. Add to that the fact that in some cases the C headers are handled by a completely separate development team. The cost of this approach is prohibitive.

To answer the final question, either use `#include <stdlib.h>` and `malloc` or use `#include <cstdlib>` and `std::malloc`.

Comment: Which of those two ways is used in the real world? Which should I use if I could go either way?

Comment: I always use eg `<stdlib.h>`.  But it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I always use `<cstdlib>`. But it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I always use neither of them. But it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I always use both of them. But it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @BetaCarotin: There's little reason to call `malloc` in C++, unless you are interfacing with C libraries, that transfer ownership. If you have no restrictions, and could pick either way, consider taking the third option: `operator new`.

Comment: @IInspectable My question was not specifically about `stdlib` or `malloc`, but C headers in general.

Comment: @BetaCarotin: You will see either one in the real world. Pick whatever your coding conventions demand. If you don't have coding conventions, install them, using this as your first convention. It doesn't really matter which one you pick. All that matters is consistency.

Comment: @Pete Are you sure about the old rule? IIRC, it used to be that .h headers had to declare the functions in namespace std and import them in the global namespace, so with stdlib.h you would have access to both std::malloc and ::malloc. As Solaris shows, it could be implemented without duplicating the declarations.

Comment: @MarcGlisse - could be for that direction. That was certainly the proclaimed goal of some folks in the early days: implement the entire standard library in C++ and layer the C stuff on top of the C++.

Comment: Why did it turn out to be impractical? Could an implementation not just use e.g. `namespace std {#include <stdio.h>}` for cstdio?

Comment: @immibis - that might succeed in telling the compiler that there are a bunch of names in `std` but it won't build a matching library and the linker won't find any of those functions.